# Using Ramda.js memoize in order to cache angular2 http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, ramda.js

I am trying to cache an http call using Ramda's [`R.memoize`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#memoize) as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class GeolocationService {

  private urls;
  private cachedAddressAutocomplete;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.urls = URLS;
    this.cachedAddressAutocomplete = R.memoize(input => {
      const body = 'address=' + input;
      return this.http.get(this.urls.GEOLOCATION.ADDRESS_AUTOCOMPLETE + body).map(res => res.json());
    });
  }

  addressAutocomplete(input: string) {
    return this.cachedAddressAutocomplete(input);
  }

  chooseAddress = (input$: Observable<string>): Observable<string> => {
    return input$
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(input => input.length < 3 ? [] : this.addressAutocomplete(input));
  };

  addressFormatter = param => param.description;
}
```

from my calling component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  providers: [FormStatusService]
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  chooseAddress = this.geolocationService.chooseAddress;
  addressFormatter = this.geolocationService.addressFormatter;
  ...
```

`chooseAddress` is used by ng bootstrap as follows:

```
 <input type="text"
         formControlName="address"
         [ngbTypeahead]="chooseAddress"
         [inputFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         [resultFormatter]="addressFormatter"
         autocomplete="off"
         class="form-control"/>
```

However, I noticed in the chrome console that the http/ajax call is always issued even if the input is the same as a previous one.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a good idea to combine observables with `memoize` this way. `http.get` returns an observable. Each `subscribe()` call triggers it and causes a new request. No caching, yes memory leaks. If you're really after caching, I would suggest to use a proper cache (with expiration and capacity limit) instead of memoize on the results, i.e. `res.json()`.

Comment: Doesn't Angular's `http` method itself include a cache?

Comment: @ScottSauyet angular2 does not include a cache. RxJS might (see `publishLast().refCount()` but I am not sure it will take into account arguments and cache accordingly...

Comment: I'm assuming that however `input$: Observable<string>` translates into the variable `input`, it's not using a version that Ramda can recognize as equal.  Is there any chance you can extract the raw string to pass?

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I definitely confirm that the input to the memoized function is a plain string. Somehow the http call is re-issued at each invocation of the memoized function. I am investigating. Please bear with me... :-)

Comment: The behavior exhibited is due to `this.http.get(this.urls.GEOLOCATION...` evaluating lazily.. I am trying to find a way to make it eager without subscribing to it... Therefore, ramda is doing its job. It is just my usage of rxjs that is flawed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired behavior by turning the http observable returned by my ramda-memoized function from **cold to hot** as follows:

```js
@Injectable()
export class GeolocationService {

  private urls;
  private cachedAddressAutocomplete;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.urls = URLS;
    this.cachedAddressAutocomplete = R.memoize(input => {
      const body = 'address=' + input;
      return this.http.get(this.urls.GEOLOCATION.ADDRESS_AUTOCOMPLETE + body)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .publishLast().refCount();//http is hot now!
    });
  }

  addressAutocomplete(input: string) {
    return this.cachedAddressAutocomplete(input);
  }

  chooseAddress = (input$: Observable<string>): Observable<string> => {
    return input$
      .debounceTime(500)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(input => input.length < 3 ? [] : this.addressAutocomplete(input));
  };

  addressFormatter = param => param.description;
}
```

By default observable returned by angular2' http are cold. See Thoughtram blog post  here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

By using `.publishLast().refCount();` one can make the http Observable **hot** (instead of **cold** by default).

Now when the input is the same as a previous one, the http call is not reissued!

P.S. *Feel free to comment this answer if you have suggestions or remarks.*

Comment: I'm not quite following the Angular hot-cold bit as to how it affects http, even after (admittedly very quickly) reading that article.  But I'm glad you got your solution.

Comment: Thanks for that Scott !